# 2011 Moderator Elections - Town Hall Chat: 7pm UTC on the 30th

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

[**Click here to join the Town Hall chat room**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/244/cstheory-town-hall-chat)

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Sunday the 30th at 7pm UTC, or 2pm EST.**

[**view in other timezones**](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=1&day=30&year=2011&hour=19&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match.  <s>I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase. there are not enough candidates for a primary phase which means you'll jump right to the election phase.  This means that I am looking at the 28th-30th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".</s>
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=cstheory.stackexchange.com).  You can register for the event [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/244/cstheory-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule).
- **You must have 20 rep on a SE site to speak in the chat room.**
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be [permanently linked here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/244).

Comment: I'm excited :) Chat has been one of the most inactive parts of this community, and I hope that people actively participate in this event.

Comment: sounds like a great idea.

Comment: I'm at POPL right now, so I'm not sure I'll be able to participate in a chat, at least until the 3rd.

Comment: I can certainly be in the chatroom whenever my computer is on. EU project deliverables are due on Feb 1, so I'll be at my computer 12-14 hours a day.

Comment: I have to say sorry but I may not be able to attend the chat, because of the timezone issue. I'll join the chat if I'm still awake by that time...

Comment: Why do we need to "register" for an online chat? Who needs to register – the candidates or all participants? What does registration mean here? What happens if I just try to join the chat without registering first?

Comment: @JukkaSuomela, Registering just means you'll get a reminder notification.

Comment: @Rebecca Still waiting for our transcript :(. the SO transcript is up, and they started after us !!

Comment: I could have *sworn* I posted it.  HRM ):  I'll get on that right now, sorry.

Comment: @Rebecca thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who participated, particularly the candidates!

The full transcript to the Town Hall Chat can be found [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/244).

Whether you were able to attend or are just reading the transcript now, I hope this helps get to know the candidates before you vote. (:

---

The following questions were asked (click to be taken directly to that point in the transcript):

- [Should we be worried about the number of unanswered questions compared to other sites?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/433959#433959)
- [How would you handle a question raised on meta regarding your moderation actions?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/433991#433991)
- [How would you handle a question that a mod closed that you feel shouldn't have been?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/434034#434034)
- [Sometimes leaving a question open is harmful to the community, how do you draw a line?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/434053#434053)
- [Recently there have been some disagreements on meta with SOIS.  Who's side are you on?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/434072#434072)
- [What should be done with off-topic q's that get answers/upvotes - the community wants?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/434074#434074)
- [What can we do to keep the quality up to help attract professional users who'll stick around?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/434100#434100)
- [Should we encourage or discourage questions that ask for HW problems (not solutions)?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/434130#434130)
- [Do you think the range of topics popular in the SE are healthy, should we spur changes?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/434148#434148)
- [What is something concrete that you think CSTheory can do to improve/grow itself?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/434191#434191)
- [How do you think your asking/answering abilities/time will be affected by being a mod?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/434239#434239)

Comment: For those who wonder: SOIS stands for Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, sorry about that - thanks for clarifying!

Comment: You’re welcome, and no need to be sorry.  Thanks for the summary of the questions!